# Ionic 2 large tab icon not displaying correctly in iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a large icon in a tabbar that is positioned at the top. When I try to enlarge an icon to around 1.5em it partly appears cut off from view. I tried making the `.tabbar` height larger and increased z-index but the icon is still cut off from view - see below image

This does not happen on Android. The icon is viewable in correct size

[image]

**Bug with iOS larger iOS tabbar**

**Tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs  [ngClass]="my_custom_class" selectedIndex="1" tabsPlacement="top"  no-shadow no-border no-border-top no-border-bottom >
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="" tabIcon="icon-controller-stop" (ionSelect)="changeCustomClass('tabbar_normal')" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="" tabIcon="icon-circle" (ionSelect)="changeCustomClass('tabbar_transp')" ></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="" tabIcon="icon-triangle-up" (ionSelect)="changeCustomClass('tabbar_normal')"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**Custom theme/icons.scss**

Problem happens with standard ionic icons also

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?b6z7qh');
  src:  url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.eot?b6z7qh#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf?b6z7qh') format('truetype'),
    url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.woff?b6z7qh') format('woff'),
    url('../assets/fonts/icomoon.svg?b6z7qh#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
  /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
  font-family: 'icomoon' !important;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size:0.55em;
  padding:0.1em;
  z-index: 999999;

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.ion-ios-icon-circle:before,
.ion-ios-icon-circle-outline:before
 {
  content: "\e900";
  font-size:1.7em;
}
```

Comment: This is likely due to Android not clipping views that overflow their parents, but it's hard to say without more information. Maybe including your style and layout source would be helpful.

Comment: I updated with tabs content and scss from icons.scss.